# Programmatically Changing ASP.NET C# Tab Title Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to change the Tab text when I navigate to a page. I have many many pages so I don't want to go to each page and add a title control. Instead I am trying to change the MasterPage.master.cs so I only have to add that one bit of code.

The following code is close to what I would like MasterPage.master.cs:

> Page.Header.Title = this.Page.ToString():

This would display "ASP.shipping_aspx" (page name is Shipping.aspx) but I would like it to display "Shipping".

How can I programmatically change the tab title text so that it changes whenever I navigate to a new page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string title = this.Page.ToString().Split('.')[1].Split('_')[0];

Page.Header.Title = char.ToUpper(title[0]) + title.Substring(1);
```